# getting grub error 17 after booting

Tags: grub2

my laptop has 80 gb hard disk. I installed windows xp and left 10 gb as unpartitioned space. Later i installed ubuntu 8.4 on the 10gb space. I got a 10.10 ubuntu version cd. I was installing it over the ubuntu 8.4 partition space. While installing,my laptop switched off and installation could not complete. whenever i boot, i get grub error 17.
earlier, both ubuntu and windows were listed...

how to recover grub?

thanks,
kan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't attempt it. Since the installation didn't complete, do it again.

Answer (score 1):

You must install 10.10 again (and complete it). After that, you will have GRUB with Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows too.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your laptop "went away" when it had finished copying files, you can boot from CD, then mount up your local linux partition and chroot to it (mount proc and bind /dev inside your intended chroot) then just rerun grub installation (grub-install ) and you should have everything up and running. If you are unsure just initiate installation again and make sure it completes this time or monitor it, so you know where it stops.